# Can linear classification take non binary targets?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm following a TensorFlow example that takes a bunch of features (real estate related) and "expensive" (ie house price) as the binary target.

I was wondering if the target could take more than just a 0 or 1. Let's say, 0 (not expensive), 1 (expensive), 3 (very expensive).

I don't think this is possible as the logistic regression model has asymptotes nearing 0 and 1.

This might be a stupid question, but I'm totally new to ML.

Comment: You don't mention the algorithm which is used. Classic logistic regression and most of the linear classifiers work only on binary classes (and sometimes there are direct multiclass formulations; so there are linear classifiers supporting multiple classes). NN-based approaches are much easier to modify to use multiple-classes: just use a final softmax-layer.

Comment: That's a good question. I thought tf.contrib.learn.LinearClassifier would use logistic regression but I can't seem to find it documented. Am I missing something?

Comment: Well, the first doc-like thing i read [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/shard1/tf.contrib.learn.LinearClassifier.md) is ready to take multiple classes.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer myself. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression):

> First, the conditional distribution y|x is a Bernoulli distribution rather than a Gaussian distribution, because the dependent variable is binary. Second, the predicted values are probabilities and are therefore restricted to (0,1) through the logistic distribution function because logistic regression predicts the probability of particular outcomes.

Comment: Well there is also [multiclass Logistic Regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression). The names are kind of irritating. The algorithm in TF you mentioned, uses a logistic loss-function, but also supports multiclass (for some learning-algs), but i'm not sure how it's working. I didn't find a softmax-layer but i'm not a TF user.

Answer (score 0):

Logistic Regression is defined for binary classification tasks.(For more details, please [logistic_regression](https://github.com/upul/logistic_regression). For multi-class classification problems, you can use Softmax Classification algorithm. Following tutorials shows how to write a Softmax Classifier in Tensorflow Library.

[Softmax_Regression in Tensorflow](https://github.com/upul/tensorflow_tutorial/blob/master/Softmax_Regression.ipynb)

However, your data set is linearly non-separable (most of the time this is the case in real-world datasets) you have to use an algorithm which can handle nonlinear decision boundaries. Algorithm such as Neural Network or SVM with Kernels would be a good choice. Following IPython notebook shows how to create a simple Neural Network in Tensorflow.

[Neural Network in Tensorflow](https://github.com/upul/tensorflow_tutorial/blob/master/Shallow_Neural_Network.ipynb)

Good Luck!